# How do I specify origin of css active to deactive state?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following script in my html page that selects two divs that take up the left and right side of the screen. When one is clicked I want it to expand to fill the screen while the other shrinks. This code works perfectly when I click the right side, but when I click the left, it shrinks the right side from right to left. How would I flip which way the right div shrinks?

```
<div class="left">
    <span>Register</span>
</div>
<div class="right">
    <span>Log In</span>
</div>

<script>
        let left = document.querySelector('.left');
        let right = document.querySelector('.right');
        console.log(right);
        left.onclick = function () {
            left.classList.toggle('active');
            right.classList.toggle('deactive');
        };

        right.onclick = function () {
            left.classList.toggle('deactive');
            right.classList.toggle('active');
        };

</script>
```

```
.left {
    top: 0vh;
    left: 0vw;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: rgb(33, 216, 88);
    height: 100vh;
    width: 50vw;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.right {
    top: 0vh;
    left: 50vw;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: rgb(56, 111, 230);
    height: 100vh;
    width: 50vw;
    left: 50%;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.left.active {
    width: 100vw;
}

.left.deactive {
    width: 0vw;
}

.right.active {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100vw;
}

.right.deactive {
    width: 0vw;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your right div shrinks, move it to the end of the screen with `left: 100%`:

```
.right.deactive {
    width: 0vw;
    left: 100%;
    overflow: hidden; /* this will hide contents */
}
```

Comment: This works, however when toggled back to its initial state, the scroll bars will flash as overflow switches from hidden too early.

Comment: @TheCanadian move overflow property to  `.right {...}` so it will be permanent. It will be ok, as it just hides the contents only when the content sticks out